# Issue With Doctrine DBAL and SQL Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm attempting to run the following query on MSSQL Server, using Doctrine DBAL:

```
$sql = "declare @new_id_num int;
        set @new_id_num = 111111;
        select @new_id_num as [ID_NUM];";

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$newIDNum = $statement->fetchAll();
```

However, all I'm getting back in $newIDNum is an empty array.
I'm not sure what to make of that - the query runs fine in a normal SQL console.
Trace seems fine - you can see the correct query being run..

I imagine I'm missing something simple?

Comment: The first thing I would _guess_ is happening is that `SET @new_id_num = 111111;` is being counted as a result set. One way to avoid this would be using `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the start of your query. One way you could test this is seeing whether `$statement->nextRowset();` after executing fetches the correct result (or whatever the equivalent is for you, I'm not sure how doctrine works but I assume it's using PDO syntax in PHP).

Answer (score 1):

ZLK was correct in that it was returning multiple rowsets.
However, you cannot call ->nextRowset() directly from the DBAL statement.
You have to get the underlying PDO statement, and call nextRowset() on that

```
$statement->getWrappedStatement()->nextRowset();
$newIDNum = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ben!

I share an example with a procedure

```
$myquery = "DECLARE @return_value int,
            @param1 varchar(32),
            @out1 varchar(32),
            @out2 varchar(32)

            EXEC @return_value = MY_PROC
                                   @param1 = N'foo',
                                   @out1= @out1 OUTPUT,
                                   @out2 = @out2 OUTPUT

            SELECT @out1 AS out1, @out2 AS out2";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($myquery);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->getWrappedStatement()->nextRowset();
$myOutputs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```